# Why risc-v ADDI instruction don't take 12 bits value in hex?

Tags: riscv32

ADDI instruction takes -1 and extends it to 32bits as below

```
addi t1, zero, -1
(gdb) info register t1
t1             0xffffffff       -1
```

But when imm12 value is 0x800, it throws illegal operand error. Why?
I see it has an issue when the MSB(11th bit) of imm12 is set to 1 like 0x800, 0xc00. It don't complain for 0x400.

```
addi t1, zero, 0x800
Error: illegal operands `addi t1,zero,0x800'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error in my riscv gcc, and it is probably because 0x800 is treated as 2048 in decimal (0x00000800), not -2048 (0xFFFFF800). So you might have to sign-extend it manually.

The smallest number accepted for addi is 0xFFFFF800 (-2048), and largest number is 0x000007FF (2047), so 0x00000800 (2048) is out of that range.

I found useful assembly macro in [test_macros.h in riscv-tests github](https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-tests/blob/master/isa/macros/scalar/test_macros.h), and you can use it like `addi t1, zero, SEXT_IMM(0x800)`

```
#define SEXT_IMM(x) ((x) | (-(((x) >> 11) & 1) << 11))
```

I don't have enough knowledge for assembler and not native speaker of English, so sorry if something of my answer is wrong.

EDIT: the macro seems to extend 12bits value only, so it can be used only for I-type instructions.